# How do I use ngrok to show on the internet a PrestaShop 1.7 site on a local Wampserver64 server?

Tags: windows-10, wampserver, prestashop-1.7, ngrok

I want to show the employers my prestashop 1.7 website that runs on the local server Wampserver. For this I want to use the ngrok utility.

I am starting ngrok with the command

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite presta.loc:80

ngrok by @inconshreveable
Session Status                online
Account                       My Name (Plan: Free)
Version                       2.3.40
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://xxxxxxxxxxx.ngrok.io -> http://presta.loc:80
Forwarding                    https://xxxxxxxxxxx.ngrok.io -> http://presta.loc:80
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

And after that I get to the main page of my site using the link provided

```
http://xxxxxxxxxxx.ngrok.io
```

But the problem is that when I try to use any links on this site and I get to my local server.

If I could change all absolute links on my site to relative links, then everything would work fine. But apparently, I can't change this in any way, because the PrestaShop does not give this opportunity.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. How can I show a employers my website on the Internet using a ngrok?

So that he can follow all the links on this site, not just the main page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the "**domain**" URL value in DB from the local one to the ngrok one in "**PS_SHOP_URL**" table.

Prestashop will use that value to generate public URLs

Then make sure to regenerate htaccess from the SEO&URL page in backoffice.